# Data Assumptions for AIC model comparisons

Tags: model-selection, independence, aic, assumptions

I recently started digging into statistical information criteria, more specifically the Akaike Information Criterion. As the literature I have read so far does not cover this, I was wondering whether certain assumptions were made in the derivation wrt to the data itself. E.g. does it require that the data is iid or is this only an implicit constraint when actually estimating the model parameters.

Comment: please expand on your question. What did you read on AIC, what kind of assumptions are you aware of, etc. I can give several examples where AIC does not work, at least not without modifications, but I would need to see where you are standing now.

Comment: AIC is about a model, not about raw data. Without a model you have neither the log-likelihood element, nor the penalty element constituting the AIC.